# Create a class within main activity

Tags: java, android, class, oncreate

What is the best way to load a class within the `onCreate` statement of an activity? I have two classes, one (titled second) is to be "loaded" when the main activity begins. Hopefully my example code will better explain what I'm trying to say:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);
    <some class here>;
}
```

I have been trying a few things, one for example is: `Date.class.cast(null);`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "load a class"?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely certain of what you're trying to do, but what you've kinda described is instantiating a class. You can do that like this:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

To load a class you just have to use it.  If all you want is a reference to the class you can use

```
Class myClass = MyClass.class;
```